# Missing temp folder in elastic beanstack with newspaper library

Tags: flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-newspaper

Every once in a while, the temp folder on my deployment server seems to go missing. I am using Flask and Newspaper on AWS elastic beanstalk. I am using the Newspaper library to scrape meta tags from external urls.

Error on the server:
{'code_content': 500, 'error': "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/.newspaper_scraper/article_resources'"}

Everything works fine after the server is restared. Is there a config setting that might fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've had a similar problem using AWS Elastic Beanstalk platform "Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux". There was a daily cron-job (`/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`) running that deletes all files in the `/tmp` folder that are older than 10 days.

Try placing the `.newspaper_scraper` folder somewhere else.

Comment: Same here, all my temp files disappeared after 10 days.  This was the only reference I could find that explained it - it's not documented anywhere in AWS!